# PHP $_SESSION between different pages recalled from different domains (but located in the same domain)

Tags: php, session, dns

i have this problem: i have two sites, for example SITEA and SITE B

from SITEA.COM, the user goes into this page (SITEA.COM/gopage)
that has the following code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['example'] = "example";       
header("Location: SITEB.COM");
```

in SITEB.com,  i have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="SITEA.COM/include/script.js.php"></script>
```

in script.js.php (called by SITEB.COM, but hosted on SITEA.COM) i have

```
<?php 
   header("Content-Type: text/javascript");

     session_start();

     ... php code that generates a dynamic javascript code
```

The problem is that my php code  in this last page cannot read $_SESSION['example'], despite they are both on SITEA.COM

if they are recalled from different domains the $_SESSION doesnt work?

Comment: A session is only available for the one domain. What are you trying to do? Someone should be able to provide an alternative.

Comment: siteA is a mobile-version site, siteB is a desktop-version site.

in siteB i want to include my script.js.php, that autoredirects (based on useragent) to siteA if you are using a mobile device

in siteA there is the link "GO TO DESKTOP VERSION", that is supposed to go to siteB.com and disable (with the session) the autoredirect to siteA.

Answer (score 1):

```
if they are recalled from different domains the $_SESSION doesnt work?
```

Indeed. This is by design. A session is bound to one web domain. Otherwise, marketeers and similar folk would be able to track your session as you travel the interwebs. You will simply have to abandon the route you're taking now: It will not work.

An alternative that is commonly used, is to build a query string when you redirect the user to the other website. In your code, you would change it to:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['example'] = "example";       
header("Location: SITEB.COM/?example=" . $_SESSION['example']);
```

Then, on the other website you could check $_GET['example'] and recreate the session like so:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['example'] = $_GET['example']
```

It's not a completely transparent solution, but it comes quite close.

Comment: I thought since both the php files that work with the session are in the same domain, i could follow that route. Since that's not possible, i have to figure out something else, but i can't use your hint because the redirect is to SITEB.COM/index.html, while my script is included in it as a javascript (.js.php), so it cant read the query string...

Comment: The included PHP file may be in the same domain, but the browser has requested another domain initially. Sessions from one domain will never be given to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

> if they are recalled from different
>   domains the $_SESSION doesnt work?

Correct.